# I want to disable login of admin (/wp-admin) with email and make it accessible only with username

Tags: wp-admin, admin, login, security

I want to do it as a security precaution. I've already taken other actions. But I want to be able to login only with my admin username. Is there a way to do that or even a plugin?

Comment: Just FYI, some users don't like plugin suggestion questions. Your best bet is editing the question to focus on the coding side of making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can disable login by email by removing the specific authenticate filter:

```php
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password', 20 );
```

from a plugin or your theme's functions.php. This won't update the UI though, which will still say 'Username or Email Address'.

Comment: Hey @Rup, so I just add this line to my theme's functions.php?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Assuming it's your own theme: if it's something that'll autoupdate then that this line would get lost when it does. You could also make a very simple plugin or mu-plugin with just this too.